# How to reduce whitespace on Twenty Seconds Resume

Tags: tikz-pgf, cv, white-space

I'm just curious if there is any way to reduce the amount of white space between the gray rectangular section (drawn using tikz) and the text to the right in the Twenty Seconds Resume format found here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-resume-slash-cv/mhyfwrmwjkbc.

I like the format, but I'd like to squeeze in a little more text per line than is currently available.
Attaching a picture to indicate what I'm trying to remove (or reduce)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please read [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and maybe edit your post so you can get more people to help and it would be easier for us to contribute. We are happy to assist :)

Answer (score 2):

*N.B.:* You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality **other people's documents** which are tailored to their *specific* needs.  Therefore it is close to **impossible to perform any modifications** on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.

Go to `twentysecondcv.cls` and edit line 112:

```
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
```

Change `-5cm` to e.g. `-4.7cm`

```
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-4.7cm,0.5cm){};
```

Also edit line 261:

```
\RequirePackage[left=7.6cm,top=0.1cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

Change `left=7.6cm` to `left=7.3cm`:

```
\RequirePackage[left=7.3cm,top=0.1cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```